# Fast image search java?

Tags: java, autohotkey

So i'm making a bot for a game, and I realy need a fast way to find a bunch of pixels(or image). I did a for loop going trhough all the pixels with Robot but that's way to slow. AHK has got a ImageSearch command that works perfectly but how can I run that from java and get the coordinates?

Comment: Use sockets to connect Java to AHK and visa versa.

Comment: You could use `AutoHotkey.dll` in conjunction with JNI, or the more special `NativeCall`, as described in [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX0iT0NTTjw).

Comment: @MCL may have an even better idea. Or you could communicate via JNA which if it can be done, is often simpler to use than JNI.

Comment: I know that GDI+ has pretty fast methods to read pixels, but I have no idea how you would implement it in java.